# Checking if string contains values of nested lists - python

Tags: python, nested-lists

First of all, do you know why this code doesn't work at all? When I give it the input 'when was steve jobs born' it returns nothing. Secondly I'm almost certain this can be written in a more efficent way which would take less time for the program to execute. Any ideas? Thanks!

```
import sys

Bill_Gates = ["bill gates","1955", "Co-founder of Microsoft"]
Steve_Jobs = ["steve jobs","1955", "Co-Founder of Apple"]
Albert_Einstein = ["albert einstein","1879", "Phycisist"]

PEOPLE = [Bill_Gates, Steve_Jobs, Albert_Einstein]

userInput = input("say something")

#checking if userInput contains the peoples name
if userInput in [j for i in PEOPLE for j in i]:
    for i in range(len(PEOPLE)):
        if PEOPLE [i][0] in userInput:
            if "when was" in userInput:
                if "born" in userInput:
                    print(PEOPLE[i][0] + "was born in " + PEOPLE[i][1])
```

UPDATE:
Ahsanul Haque gave me just the answer I was searching for.

Answer (score 4):

You should try to debug these kinds of problems yourself by breaking down what happens at each step. Printing the variables at each stage or playing around with a shell or debugger such as `pdb` are very helpful. In this case:

```
>>> Bill_Gates = ["bill gates","1955", "Co-founder of Microsoft"]
>>> Steve_Jobs = ["steve jobs","1955", "Co-Founder of Apple"]
>>> Albert_Einstein = ["albert einstein","1879", "Phycisist"]
>>> 
>>> PEOPLE = [Bill_Gates, Steve_Jobs, Albert_Einstein]
>>> things = [j for i in PEOPLE for j in i]
>>> things
['bill gates', '1955', 'Co-founder of Microsoft', 'steve jobs', '1955', 'Co-Founder of Apple', 'albert einstein', '1879', 'Phycisist']
>>> 'steve jobs' in things
True
>>> 'when was steve jobs born' in things
False
```

So the `if userInput in [j for i in PEOPLE for j in i]` fails because the right hand side is just a list of strings and Python isn't magic.

Your code is almost there anyway, as it works without the initial check. So this works:

```
for person in PEOPLE:
    if person[0] in userInput and "when was" in userInput and "born" in userInput:
        print(person[0] + " was born in " + person[1])
```

Note that a direct for loop works in this situation; there is no need to use `range` and index manually. Using the `and` operator is also cleaner than nested `if` statements.

This is plenty efficient as is unless `PEOPLE` has some tens of millions of elements. If you get to that stage you can look into search engine indexing techniques.

Answer (score 2):

`'when was steve jobs born'` isn't in that list you made, whatever it is; since the outer `if` fails, nothing inside it gets executed.

Answer (score 1):

What about making a `Person` class? It's simple, readable and easy to manage.

For example, I've written a `Person` class with a `get_role` method. Write your own `get_name()` and `get_year_of_birth` method.

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name, year_of_birth, role):
        self.name = name
        self.year_of_birth = year_of_birth
        self.role = role

    def get_role(self):
        return self.role

Bill_Gates = Person("bill gates","1955", "Co-founder of Microsoft")
Steve_Jobs = Person("steve jobs","1955", "Co-Founder of Apple")
Albert_Einstein = Person("albert einstein","1879", "Phycisist")


person_list= [Bill_Gates,Steve_Jobs,Albert_Einstein]


for person in person_list:
    print person.get_role()
```

Output:

```
Co-founder of Microsoft
Co-Founder of Apple
Phycisist
```

Comment: Thanks, just what I was looking for.

Comment: @UlrikKarlsson Glad that it helped. If you feel that the answer satisfies your question, you could consider accepting the answer, rather than mentioning it in the question. That will help the fellow users.